# Function abs() in C++ console project

Tags: c++, math

I don't know which library is better to use for abs(my_integer) function?

```
<cstdlib>
<cmath> (C++)
<math.h> (C)
```

Comment: It's C++, so use the C++ header.

Comment: @paddy, you mean <cmath>?

Comment: @paddy, but why I shouldn`t use <cstdlib>? or <cmath> is better than <cstdlib>?

Comment: Yes, I just realized this is the thrust of your question.  I always use `<cmath>` personally.

Comment: In C++, `std::abs()` is declared in both `<cstdlib>` and `<cmath>`  (and they resolve to the same set of function definitions). So, if the only function you care about is `std::abs()` it doesn't matter which header you use. If you are also using other functions from `<cstdlib>`, but no others from `<cmath>`, including `<cstdlib>` is sufficient.  If you are also using other functions from `<cmath>`, but no others from `<cstdlib>`, including `<cmath>` is sufficient. If you are also using functions from both `<cstdlib>` and `<cmath>` not declared in both, you need to include both. In short - Doh!

Comment: @Peter, I`m using only abs(), I am not using other function from cmath or cstdlib. So which one is better? Also, I notice that iostream automatically including cstdlib functions, so I can use abs() only including iostream

Comment: 'better' cannot be defined in this case. ANd latter isn't guaranteed, a different version of same compiler may behave differently.

Comment: @RoyalCat   If the only function you're using is `abs()`, it doesn't matter which header you use.   You can use both if you like - makes no functional difference to the end result.   And any non-functional differences (microseconds difference in build times, size of executable, etc) don't really matter - what is "best" (however you define that!) for one compiler/library is probably not "best" for another compiler/library.

Answer (score 2):

Following overloads of abs are defined in both `cstdlib` and `cmath` headers, within namespace `std` and can be propagated to global namespace:

```
int       abs( int n );
long      abs( long n );
long long abs( long long n );
```

That's likely done to be consistent with different standards, e.g. POSIX stating them being declared in `stdlib.h`, and many of older C++ implementations declare some of those overloads in `math.h` because of C++98 inconsistency.

Currently, use of `math.h` in C++ is deprecated.

Note, none of those header files are considered "libraries" per se. They provide part of implementation, guaranteed by standard  and likely are interface to runtime library or `inline` \ `constexpr` implementations.

Current draft offers as well

```
float abs(float j);
double abs(double j);
long double abs(long double j);
```

but current GCC implementation provides those in `std` namespace only.

Comment: Technically, C++ code that uses `<math.h>` is compliant.   It, like a lot of other C headers, has been deprecated by C++ standards.  Deprecated means their usage is formally allowed, but there is a risk they will no longer be allowed by a future standard.   No C++ standard has yet disallowed them and, to date, there has been no proposal to actually disallow them.

Comment: Thanks, sorry, I can't vote up because I haven't enough reputation

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your use case, In case you are doing competitive programming or you need to code your program really fast to test something small, then I prefer using `<bits/stdc++.h>` this will include all possible library functions in c++. But for all other cases I prefer using `<cmath>` becasue from a code reader point of view, this correctly implicates that I am doing something mathematical in this program. Performance wise, I dont think you could measure any difference on whatever you use.

Answer (score -2):

man page for `abs()` (https://linux.die.net/man/3/abs) says `#include <stdlib.h>`. So in C++ you should `#include <cstdlib>` and use it as `std::abs()` to be completely conformant.

cppreference (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/abs) also mentions `<cstdlib>` can be used, but also mentions `<cmath>`.

Final conclusion: in C++, any of `<cmath>` or `<cstdlib>` can be used, both of them declare these functions.

Comment: but why I shouldn`t use  <cmath> - it is C++ header too? What`s the difference?

Comment: man isn't correct source.  it's related to POSIX C standard

Comment: You should consult man page for the function to find out which header to use. `<cmath>` likely provides `abs()` overload for the floating-point values.

Comment: Yes, man may be POSIX, but it is working documentation that gives you working information, so I'd prefer to always look into man.

Comment: You're taking a C reference and assuming it applies equally to C++. That is not the case here.

Comment: C functions are available in C++. Btw cppreference also points to <cstdlib>.

Comment: the man page for Linux isn't the C or C++ manual. It contains many extensions that don't even exist in C and C++ standards

Comment: The C++ standard specifies that the `abs` functions are declared in both headers.  It does not indicate one header being more fit for purpose than the other.

Comment: agree, but not in this case. extensions are usually clearly marked like "this is GNU extension".

Comment: Here is the relevant part of the Standard, which makes no mention of GNU or any other implementation: http://eel.is/c++draft/c.math.abs

Comment: `You should consult man page for the function to find out which header to use. <cmath> likely provides abs()` which is part of C++ standard. And stdlib.h may not provide `long long` version in older compilers because C didn't had it albeit it was is guaranteed by C++. Also C++ version might be inlined (not constexpr yet, we awaiting that to happen)